# Add a delay before playing an audio using Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I want to play 5 audio's at a go but with different time delays. Like (a.mp3 with a time delay of 2 sec, b.mp3 = 4 sec etc) but i dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use handler.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
final static int DELAY = 1000; // one second

public void playAudioWithDelay(){
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    //your code start with delay in one second after calling this method
  }, DELAY);
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    //your code start with delay in two seconds after calling this method
  }, DELAY * 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man!!! you just saved me! I have searched and searched and searched but no luck. You are a pro bro.